# How center my buttons? depends the my first button

Tags: xamarin.forms

Im tried to center my two buttons, i want that my first butto be in the center and my second button be next to my first button, for example

```
-----------------------------
-                           -
-                           -
-                           -
-                           -
-          -----------      -
-          - 1  - 2  -      -
```

The buttons should be in down center

```
<StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Button Text="Here" BackgroundColor="Aqua" WidthRequest="100" />

                <Button Text="Max" WidthRequest="50"
                BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>
</StackLayout>
```

but i with my code i get

```
-----------------------------
-                           -
-                           -
-                           -
-                           -
-           -----           -
-           -1-2-           -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want to center the first button,then the second button beside it ?

If yes,you could consider using [RelativeLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout).

```
<RelativeLayout   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red">
   <Button Text="Here" BackgroundColor="Aqua" WidthRequest="100"  RelativeLayout.XConstraint ="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                         Property=Width,
                         Factor=.5,
                         Constant= -50}"/>

   <Button Text="Max" WidthRequest="50" BackgroundColor="Yellow"   RelativeLayout.XConstraint ="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,                           
                         Property=Width,
                         Factor=.5,
                         Constant= 60}"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you help me with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61073136/how-can-i-click-in-a-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to achieve, your code should be like below:-

```
        <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Button Text="Here" BackgroundColor="Aqua" WidthRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                <Button Text="Max" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>
        </StackLayout>
```

Let me know for further queries.

Comment: i tried with your answer but dont works, can you put a screenshot?